# How to Optimize a TensorFlow Keras Model with MultiHeadAttention and LIME for Image Classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

**Import Libraries**

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from lime import lime_image
from lime.wrappers.scikit_image import SegmentationAlgorithm
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Input, Model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
```

Here, i are importing all the required libraries. TensorFlow for deep learning, Lime for model explanation, and matplotlib for visualization among others.

```
log_dir = "logs"
os.makedirs(log_dir, exist_ok=True)

tensorboard_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
```

This section is for TensorBoard configuration. TensorBoard is a tool that provides various functionalities to understand the TensorFlow runs and graphs. i set the log directory and initialize the TensorBoard callback.

**Data Generators**

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=15,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.15
)

val_test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('Data 2/250000_Final',
                                              target_size=(28, 28),
                                              color_mode='grayscale',
                                              class_mode='sparse')

val_gen = val_test_datagen.flow_from_directory('Data 2/70000',
                                               target_size=(28, 28),
                                               color_mode='grayscale',
                                               class_mode='sparse')

test_gen = val_test_datagen.flow_from_directory('Data 2/10000',
                                                target_size=(28, 28),
                                                color_mode='grayscale',
                                                class_mode='sparse')
```

In this block, i initialize ImageDataGenerator for training, validation, and test sets. The training set generator includes data augmentation techniques like rotation, zoom, and shift to artificially increase the size of the training set and improve generalization.

**Hyperparameters**

```
num_heads = 2
key_dim = 2
```

i define hyperparameters for the MultiHeadAttention layer. num_heads represents the number of attention heads, and key_dim represents the dimension of the key vectors.

**Model Architecture**

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
reshaped = layers.Reshape(target_shape=(28 * 28, 1))(input_layer)
attention_output = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=key_dim)(reshaped, reshaped, reshaped)
flattened = layers.Flatten()(attention_output)
dropped = layers.Dropout(0.2)(flattened)
output_layer = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(dropped)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
```

This is where i define the architecture of the model using Keras' Functional API. It starts with an input layer for grayscale images of shape 28x28, applies a MultiHeadAttention layer, and finally a dense output layer with softmax activation for classification.

**Compile and Train**

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_gen, epochs=5, validation_data=val_gen, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

i compile the model specifying the optimizer, loss function, and metrics to monitor. Then, i train the model using the data generators and also use the TensorBoard callback for logging metrics.

**Evaluate the Model**

```
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_gen)
print(f'Test accuracy: {test_acc}')
```

**LIME Explainer**

```
explainer = lime_image.LimeImageExplainer()
segmenter = SegmentationAlgorithm('quickshift', kernel_size=1, max_dist=200, ratio=0.2)

def model_predict(image_batch):
    return model.predict(image_batch.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1))

image_to_explain, label_to_explain = test_gen.next()
image_to_explain = image_to_explain[0]
explanation = explainer.explain_instance(image_to_explain, model_predict, top_labels=5, hide_color=0, num_samples=1000, segmentation_fn=segmenter)
```

Finally, i use LIME to interpret the model. LIME (Local Interpretable Model-agnostic Explanations) is used to explain predictions of any classifier in an interpretable and faithful manner.

**Visualization**

```
temp, mask = explanation.get_image_and_mask(label_to_explain, positive_only=True, num_features=5, hide_rest=True)
plt.imshow(lime_image.mark_boundaries(temp, mask))
plt.show()
```

This part of the code is used to visualize the LIME explanation for an image from the test set. It helps me understand what areas of the image were most influential in making a prediction.